# SQL Server - Test to see if Table A's values are in Table B

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, boolean

I have created two table variables (each have one column):

```
Declare @CoursePrereq TABLE (Prereq char(6))
Declare @TakenCourses TABLE (Taken char(6))
```

Basically, I want to test to see if ALL of the prerequisite courses are stored in the taken column of the @TakenCourses table. If they are, that means the prerequisites have been taken and I'd like a 1 (for true) returned. Obviously, i'd like a 0 if ALL values from @CoursePrereq are not in @TakenCourses.

Is there a way to test to see if these Prereq Column values are ALL in the Taken Column? I've tried a few things (while loop with top 1, if statement, exists) and i'm stuck. Can I get some assistance?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `NOT EXISTS` to find the missing `Prereq` values in `Taken` column. And then use `CASE` expression to output `1` and `0` based on the count of the result set.

**Query**

```
SELECT CASE WHEN COUNT(*) > 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS [Status]
FROM @CoursePrereq t
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM @TakenCourses
    WHERE t.Prereq = Taken
);
```

### <kbd>[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/cfab1/97)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

Try with exists:

```
    Declare @CoursePrereq TABLE (Prereq char(6))
    Declare @TakenCourses TABLE (Taken char(6))

    insert into @CoursePrereq values ('1'),('2'),('3')
    insert into @TakenCourses values ('1'),('2'),('3'),('4')


    select case when count(*) > 1 then 1 else 0 end as 'MATCHING' from @CoursePrereq 
    where exists  
   (select * from @TakenCourses where Prereq = Taken)
```

[EXAMPLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e1c06)